# How to factor $ {s - a_m} \over {s-b_n} $ to $ {1-{s \over a_m}} \over {1 - {s \over b_n}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I saw this polynomial or algebraic equation and can verified by plugging in some numbers and figuring out the constant for a specific sets of $ a_m $ and $ b_n $. But how can I derive the equation on the right from the left? I tried multiplying both sides by s, a or b but I can't come up with anything close to the term on the right.

${{(s-a_1)(s - a_2) \; ... \; (s-a_m)} \over {(s-b_1)(s-b_2) \; ... \; (s-b_n)}} = C_0 {({1-{s \over a_1})({1 - {s \over a_2}}) \; ... \;({1 - {s \over a_m}})} \over {({1 - {s \over b_1}})({1 - {s \over b_2}}) \; ... \; ({1 - {s \over b_n}})}}$

Comment: $\dfrac{s-a_m}{s-b_n} = \dfrac{a_m}{b_n}\cdot \dfrac{1-s/a_m}{1-s/b_m}$

Comment: @MartinR but that will end up having $ {a_m - s} \over {b_n - s} $ ... reversed...

Comment: A fraction does not change if you multiply both numerator and denominator with $(-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${s-\alpha}=\alpha\left(\frac{s}{\alpha}-1\right)=(-\alpha)\left(1-\frac{s}{\alpha}\right),$$ provided $\alpha\ne0$. So

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{(s-a_1)(s - a_2) \; ... \; (s-a_m)}{(s-b_1)(s-b_2) \; ... \; (s-b_n)}& =&\frac{(-a_1)(-a_2)\cdots(-a_m)(1-s/a_1)(1-s/a_2)\cdots(1-s/a_n)}{(-b_1)(-b_2)\cdots(-b_n)(1-s/b_1)(1-s/b_2)\cdots(1-s/b_m)}\\
&=&C_0 {({1-{s \over a_1})({1 - {s \over a_2}}) \; ... \;({1 - {s \over a_m}})} \over {({1 - {s \over b_1}})({1 - {s \over b_2}}) \; ... \; ({1 - {s \over b_n}})}}\end{eqnarray}
where $$C_0=(-1)^{m-n}\frac{a_1\cdots a_m}{b_1\cdots b_m},$$